# How to enable cookies and security?

Tags: security, cookies

I have created a websites using php and html and not wordpress or anything. Since one has many advantages of using wordpress and just need to plug and play.

For my site https://www.percentagepro.com I want to enable cookies so that user can accept it and also want to have a popup to bookmark my sites. Can anyone suggest me how that can be done?

Also would like to get some inputs what all i can do extra to make it user friendly and secured.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean with '...enable cookies so that user can accept it...'? Are you having trouble actually using cookies in PHP or do you want to display first-time visitors a cookie notice with options? Perhaps [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) can help you to get started with cookies in PHP.

Comment: yes,  to display first-time visitors a cookie notice with options and also want to track what all user has done on my websites.